# Responsiveness delay in menu, most apps and right clicking

Tags: menu

Recently (after recent updates) I noticed that I am seeing some freezing.

To replicate:

1- Boot up desktop PC with GeForce GTX 750 card, 32 GB of RAM and an Intel Core i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz CPU.

2- Everything loads fine. Let PC sit for a few minutes just in case. Then try to launch Applications menu - five second or more delay. Type text into Applications menu - 7 to 10 second delay. Right click anywhere in Firefox - 10 second delay. So then I tried epiphany - right clicking works great, yet launching the epiphany settings/etc has that same delay.

3- Launch a keyboard launcher (previously closed) like synapse. Apps launch right away. Launch Chrome, terminal, Files browser - zero delays. Works great.

4 - Tried this with htop and glances running - nothing spiking or showing up that seemed odd. Nothing standing out in the logs, either.

So here's the tltr.

Ran updates, menu, Firefox right clicking all have delay - Chrome, synapse, terminal, Files do not. It's not hardware as it's replicatable and persistent only with some elements of the desktop.

Any way I can narrow down what the cause is? Tried multiple kernels and don't believe it's the video card.

Comment: Confirming this seems to affect stuff that is gtk related and certain elements of the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Well, basically with some tough love.

I purged a LOT (but not critical stuff) of my ~./config and ~./local directories and I also purged my ~./mozilla directory. My gut tells me the culprit was a combination of the group of these configs.

Some things to note - I use a dedicated home partition. So this means when I did a clean install using the same dedicated home, the problem persisted.

After cleaning out what I described above (and understanding what data would be gone and what would not), things worked just fine.

Comment: Way cool! Would this be a possible topic for a future video by any chance?